# design generic API using abstract method, but have to use final variables when pass to anonymous class. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, itext

I am trying to create an generic API that run on-top of iText. One of the function of this API is to allow the user to split the PDF to invidual page, and allow the user to add list of text onto each pdf page after the split. For example, a pdf of 20 pages, and after run this process, I will have 20 of 1-page-pdf, and the first pdf will have a text 000001 on it, and the last pdf will have 000020 on it pdf. So to accomplish this, I use abstract method that allow the developer to write code on how they want the text to format given the current page number.

```
public abstract class GenericText {

    /**
     * The X position of the text. (0, 0) is at the bottom left
     */
    private float x;

    /**
     * The Y position of the text. (0, 0) is at the bottom left
     */
    private float y;

    /**
     * The rotation of the text. Rotation 0, 90, 180, 270
     */
    private float rotation;

    /**
     * <code>com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont</code>. Determine the font for the text
     */
    private BaseFont font;

    /**
     * Determine the font size of the text
     */
    private float fontSize;

    /**
     * This tells whether text can only be placed first page or on every page
     */
    private ComponentPlacement placement;

    /**
     * Since the text that the user want to insert onto the Pdf might vary
     * from page to page, or from logical document to logical document, we allow
     * the user to write their own implementation of the text. To give the user enough
     * flexibility, we give them the reference to the physical page index, the logical page index. 
     * @param physcialPage The actual page number that the user current looking at
     * @param logicalPage A Pdf might contain multiples sub-documents, <code>logicalPage</code>
     * tell the user which logical sub-document the system currently looking at
     */
    public abstract String generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage);
    ...
}
```

PdfPrcessor.java: This is where the split happen

```
/**
 * This is the main process that will split the pdf into individual page, and text to each page
 */
public void splitPdf(String inputPdf, boolean isSplit, List<GenericText> textList, 
             String outputDir, String baseOutputName, String outputPdfName) throws IOException, DocumentException{
    ...
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf)
    PdfContentByte cb = ... ;
    for(int physicalPageIndex=1 ; physicalPageIndex<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); physicalPageIndex ++)
       ...
       //Code to split PDF. Write each page to a separate pdf. For each pdf, insert all text inside `textList` onto the pdf
       ...
       //Insert text
       if(textList != null){
         for(GenericText textComponent : textList){
            String text = textComponent.generateText(physicalPageIndex, logicalPageIndex);
            addText(text, cb, textComponent.getFont(), textComponent.getFontSize(), textComponent.getX(), textComponent.getY(), textComponent.getRotation());
         }
       }
    }
    ...
}
```

So in my main class I would do this,

```
final String printName = printNameLookup.get(baseOutputName);
final String seq = config.getPrintJobSeq();
GenericText keyline = new GenericText(90, 640, 0, arial, 7, ComponentPlacement.FIRST_PAGE){
    @Override
    public String generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage) {
         return printName + seq + " " + Utils.right(String.valueOf(logicalPage), 6, '0');
    }
};
textList.add(keyline);
pdfProcess.splitPdf(inputPdfPath, true, textList, outputDir, baseOutputName, outputPdfName);
```

This work great, and I think it is very flexible however, `printName` and `seq` has be be declared as `final` in order to pass inside `generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage)`. How do I design this so that it wont require `final` field. Will `interface` help? I use **guava API**, and I can do this

```
ImmutableListMultimap<String, File> groups = Multimaps.index(pdfList,
new Function<File, String>(){
    public String apply(File input){
        String[] ids = getId(input.getName());
        PackageLog pl = logProcessor.lookUp(new Long(ids[0]), ids[1]);
        String printName = printNameLookup.get(getPackageName(pl, s));
    }   
});
```

`logProcessor` and `printNameLookup` is not `final`, I like the way they design, and I am reading their sources now, but it will take some times, anyone with expert on design knowledge can shed me some light?

Comment: logProcessor and printNameLookup must be final if they are local variables. If they're instance fields, they don't need to be. Why do you care about your variable being forced to be final. That's a Java rule, and Guava must observe it as any other code.

Comment: @JBNizet: I see, they are infact instance field `private Map<String, String> printNameLookup;`. I test what you just said, and in fact local variable need to declare final when I pass to guava method. Sorry, I am learning how to design thing correctly, if this is standard and I will not worry about it anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Copy them into a final variables and use those instead.

```
String printName = printNameLookup.get(baseOutputName);
String seq = config.getPrintJobSeq();
// use these in the anonymous class.
final String finalPrintName = printName;
final String finalSeq = seq;
```

or use arrays

```
final String[] printName = { printNameLookup.get(baseOutputName) };
final String[] seq = { config.getPrintJobSeq() };

// use printName[0] and seq[0] everywhere.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. In this case copying the values into final variables will work.